# Possible to include non-spotify audio in Spotify apps?

Tags: spotify

Is it possible to include audio player in Spotify apps? Audio from a different source than Spotify? lets say an interview of an artist.

Answer (score 11):

From the [integration guidelines](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/):

> **Non-Spotify Audio Content**
>
> You are not allowed to playback non-Spotify audio content.

Comment: I appreciate at least that they're upfront about it, but it's quite disappointing.